# How to calculate xirr

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

Hi I am new to power bi and not sure what I am doing wrong here

I am trying to calculate XIRR for cashflow and dates present in "table1" by defining a measure. The measure creates a variable table "Data" by selecting columns from "table 1" another variable table is to for closing date and final amount - "closing_date" and then third variable is union of above two variables. Following is the code

```
XIRR = 

VAR Data = UNION(SELECTCOLUMNS(table1, "abc", [Cashflow]),SELECTCOLUMNS(table1, "xyz", [ Date]))

VAR Closing_Date = ROW("abc", TODAY(),"xyz",SUM(table1[Total value]))

VAR Final_table = UNION(Data,Closing_Date)

RETURN XIRR(Final_table, [xyz], [abc])
```

I am receiving the error "Each table argument of 'UNION' must have the same number of columns." What am I doing wrong here? Is there a better way to do this?